# Command-Line Upsert: "Internal Comments" mapping

Tags: data-loader, field-mapping, commandline, internal-comments

I'm upserting Cases by Command-Line. I need to insert the content of the field "Internal Comments" that actually is not exactly a field of Case (but instead of the object CaseComments). When I create the mapping the system obviously doesn't recognize the field.

Is there a way to map the Internal Comments directly by command-line without writing any additional code?

Comment: You have to insert the cases first, then the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the object Case you can find the "*Internal Comments*" field, but if you use the corresponding API name ("*Comments*") you find out that you cannot use that field. The reason is simple: that is not a field. Internal Comments refers to an object called CaseComments. So, as Eric suggests, you should first insert the Cases and then adding the Comments.